# Merging several value in an integer via the OR keyword

Tags: delphi

Something trivial, but i can't find any help showing how to use it. I often see in code that we can merge in a single integer several values with **OR** like this :

```
var Flags: integer;

flags := aflag1 or aflag2 or aflag3;
```

but later how to know if `aflag1` is in `flags` ? also what rules must apply to `aflag1`, `aflag2`, `aflag3` (i guess they can not be any integer number)

Comment: Potentially the flags could be anything. Not implausible that they could have more than one bit set. It all depends.

Comment: You can check for a certain flag using, e.g. `if (flags and aflag2) <> 0 then ...`  or `if (flags and aflag2) = aflag2 then ...`.

Comment: The second of Rudy's tests would be safer, in case aflag2 set more than one bit.